# Memory dumps of a 32-bit process on 64-bit Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit, dump

I used **Task Manager** *(Windows 7, 64-bit)* to dump the memory of Chrome processes.

Unfortunately, attempting to dump a 32-bit process using the (64-bit) Task Manager will generate nonsensical memory dumps.

If I did use **Task Manager** *(64-bit)* to generate a dump of a 32-bit process, is there a way to convert the already-done memory dump so that it will be properly analyzed?

Also, if you have full memory dump available, can a person re-create processes and programs running before crash occurred?

**Edit:** It seems that many people are confused of my intention:

I **already** created memory dumps of 32-bit Chrome processes using Windows **Task Manager** *(64-bit)*. Then I came to read articles that say this will create a corrupted version of memory dump.

What I am wondering is, can the dump ever be read properly with these dumps?

And also the second question.

### What do I mean corrupted?

From one of the supplied links:

> If you capture a dump with a tool that captures 64-bit dumps you will still get a memory dump, but you will get a memory dump of the syswow64 which means that a lot of extensions like sos and psscor2 won’t be able to read the data.  Some things may still work but it is very limited and you might get errors or erroneous call stacks etc.

### See also

- [Memory Dumps Done Right](http://www.devopsonwindows.com/memory-dumps-done-right/)
- [Capturing memory dumps for 32-bit processes on an x64 machine](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2010/09/29/capturing-memory-dumps-for-32-bit-processes-on-an-x64-machine.aspx)

Comment: **Have you determined the dump was even messed up?**  Provide us the link to the article it might be incorrect, written by a hack, who has no idea what they are talking about.

Comment: The link's http://www.devopsonwindows.com/memory-dumps-done-right/

Comment: @Membu  Figures its blocked.  The title of the article seems to indicate it talks about the correct way to do memory dumps, have you followed that guidence, and what was your result?

Comment: Another link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2010/09/29/capturing-memory-dumps-for-32-bit-processes-on-an-x64-machine.aspx   The reason I am asking this question is because I did not know this kind of thing, and just read these articles. So I did not follow the guidance. That's why I am asking this question.

Comment: The second article mentions tools you can use.  Have you used those tools?

Comment: ''"Also, if you have full memory dump available, can a person re-create processes and programs running before crash occurred?"'' No, sorry. The dump file does not contain enough information to re-create the process state.

Comment: Just issue `!wow64exts.sw` and you should be good. See [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/debugging-wow64). Also, note the introduction: Issues with the WoW64 layer cannot be seen from a 32-bit debugger.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Process Explorer 15.3 (or higher version) from sysinternals which is aware of the architecture and creates proper dumps.

> Process Explorer v15.3: This major Process Explorer release includes
>   heat-map display for process CPU, private bytes, working set and GPU
>   columns, sortable security groups in the process properties security
>   page, and tooltip reporting of tasks executing in Windows 8 Taskhostex
>   processes. **It also creates dump files that match the bitness of the
>   target process** and works around a bug introduced in Windows 8 disk
>   counter reporting.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sysinternals/archive/2013/02/04/updates-pendmoves-v1-2-process-explorer-v15-3-sigcheck-v1-91-zoomit-v4-42.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to convert one kind of memory dump to another.

And for anyone wondering, you should manually run the 32-bit Task Manager:

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\TaskMgr.exe

if you want to generate a dump of a 32-bit process

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Just open the dump created on windbg (either x86 or x64) and then execute the command:
".effmach x86"

This will show you the X86 context stored in the dump file. From them on all commands will work on the x86 context.

TaskManager created minidumps are always 64 bits. Remember all your Windows process running on a 64 bit Windows are 64 bit processes. It is just that when your code is 32 bits, it runs on WindownOnWindows which shims all the calls back and forth between the process (32 bits) and the OS (64 bits).